# How to place navigation bar on top in transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to place the navigation bar on top, in transparent, as the shown in the picture. I tried to pix the position and the width and height but still didn’t work.

[image]

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }

    .header {
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(img/arnold-francisca-nPhl2x4fk2s-unsplash.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav {
        display: flex;
        padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav img {
        width: 85px;
    }
    .nav-links {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .nav-links ul li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .nav-links ul li a {
        color: rgb(8, 8, 8);
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .nav-links ul li::after {
        content: '';
        width: 0%;
        height: 3px;
        background: #d6574e;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .nav-links ul li:hover::after {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .text-box {
        width: 90%;
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        text-align: center;
    }
    .text-box h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .text-box p {
        margin: 10px 0 40px;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .hero-btn {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #cfaba9;
        border: 1px solid #cfaba9;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: transparent;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .hero-btn:hover {
        border-radius: 50px;
        background: #cfaba9;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    nav .fa {
        display: none;
    }
    @media(max-width: 700px){
        .text-box h1 {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .nav-links ul li {
            display: block;
        }
        .nav-links ul li {
            position: absolute;
            background: #cfaba9;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 200px;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: left;
            z-index: 2;
        
        }
        nav .fa {
            display: block;
            color: #cfaba9;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 22px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .nav-links ul {
            padding: 30px;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nikko Permelona | UX/UI Designer, Frontend Developer &amp; Learner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.2/css/fontawesome.min.css">

    </head>


    <body>
        <section class="header"></section>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/GYSD7530-modified.png"></a>
            <div class="nav-links">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Experience</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </nav>

        <div class="text-box">
            <h1>UI/UX Designer, Frontend Developer &amp; Learner</h1>
            <p>I design and code gorgeously simple things, and I love what I do</p>
            <a href="" class="hero-btn">Explore</a>


        </div>

    </body>



    </html>
```

Comment: I keep looking at my code since last night trying to find the error but I didn’t see that I close the section next to header section…Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the `nav` and the `text-box` divs with the header section. It looks like you closed the header section right away and haven't wrapped it with anything, modify the part like this:

```
 <section class="header">
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/GYSD7530-modified.png"></a>
            <div class="nav-links">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Experience</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </nav>

        <div class="text-box">
            <h1>UI/UX Designer, Frontend Developer &amp; Learner</h1>
            <p>I design and code gorgeously simple things, and I love what I do</p>
            <a href="" class="hero-btn">Explore</a>


        </div>
</section>
```

This should work fine

Comment: I keep looking at my code since last night trying to find the error but I didn’t see that I close the section next to header section…Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can make it transparent by use the css property:
`background-color: transparent;`
Also to make the nav bar go to top try putting it in div instead of nav.

Comment: Choosing `<div>` or `<nav>` has no influence over the position of the navigation. Though `<nav>` seems to be the correct semantic choice here.